# Method of differentiation

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

First of all we all know that d/dx is an operator which differentiates the function provided to it w.r.t. x okay!

Now, while differentiating complex functions we often use Chain Rule. Sometimes during differentiation we multiply the function with the dx or du or dt etc. Also we treat dy/dx as a fraction and perform fractional manipulations on them.

For example if ***x = f(t)*** and ***y = g(t)*** then for finding dy/dx we find dy/dt and dx/dt and divide them for obtaining dy/dx.

How this happens? Since d/dx is an operator, how are we able to treat it as a fraction in differentiation and cancel dt present in numerator and denominator (as in above example) ?!
Please explain.

Comment: Tons of questions have already been posted here on the same. Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21199/734160) one out

Comment: It's a common misconception every calculus student has.

Comment: In your $x=f(t),y=g(t)$ example, suppose you are looking at derivatives when $t=t_0, x=x_0=f(t_0), y=y_0=g(t_0)$. If you apply $\frac{d}{dx}$ you get $\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x_0} = \left.\frac{dy}{dt}\right|_{t_0}\left.\frac{dt}{dx}\right|_{x_0}$.  Since, assuming good behaviour, $\left.\frac{dt}{dx}\right|_{x_0}=1/\left.\frac{dx}{dt}\right|_{t_0}$, this means $\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x_0} = \left.\frac{dy}{dt}\right|_{t_0}/\left.\frac{dx}{dt}\right|_{t_0} =\frac{g'(t_0)}{f'(t_0)}$. It may look like cancellation of the $dt$ terms but that is not the justification.

Comment: @DatBoi Thank you very much for the link.
Also thank you to all who have replied